# Tracking clicks on a webpage to a google sheet cell

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets-api

I'd like to be able to track clicks from a webpage to a google sheet via json, how can I increment values on a sheet?

What I'm looking to do is display one of these codes randomly on a page and log copy clicks (there's a button to copy the code via javascript)

[image]

**How to:**

1. increment the clicks
2. locate the cell to increment the clicks

Is this something that's possible w/ google sheets?

Comment: In order to help users correctly think of your question, can you provide the your current script and explanation of it? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm not sure if this is something that can be easily achieved to increment values specific cells on a sheet, for example `B2`, each time a user clicks on the `Copy` button for code `aaa1`, it adds 1 more to `Clicks` column, so 1 becomes 2, etc

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about `the Copy button`.

Comment: Sure, what would you like to know? When user clicks on an HTML `Copy` button on a webpage: https://i.imgur.com/WtsvsKB.png it has javascript code that increments a click value by 1 on a google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The button is put to a outer web page which is not the dialog and/or side bar on Google Spreadsheet. When the button is clicked, the value on the Google Spreadsheet is increased. You have already had the script for this and the script is not required to be modified. If my understanding is correct, what is `Code` on the cells? Also please tell me whether my understanding is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I just coded a bitly style google sheet web app and show you how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SCtkLc-uFQ
in short you get the values from the column of Codes and then you find that index of the clicks column. Then increment by one.

Comment: It's is expected that you include the important parts of the code as snippets in your answer